# Stomp + Spring + ZeroMQ for real-time

Tags: spring, spring-integration, zeromq, stomp, sockjs

I need to implement a real-time scenario via web sockets and ZeroMQ queue.

- SockJS with Stomp in the client side
- Spring MVC / Integration with @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
- Remote messaging queue with ZeroMQ

At this moement, I could connect client and Spring via web sockets but I need to add the magic of remote queues.

ZeroMQ is available from 2 remote URLs (one for publishing and another one for subscribing).

My question is: How can I implement ZeroMQ in order to stay listening subscribed URL or the publishing URL?

Additionally, this type of functionality is conceptually similar to Spring Integration Outbound Gateways which stay listening for the response. Is it possible to implement ZeroMQ via Spring integration?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We have an [open JIRA issue to add ZeroMQ support to Spring Integration](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3045).

But nothing is implemented yet; [contributions are welcome!](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

Comment: Thank you Gary. Did you have any chance to take a look at this? https://github.com/moonkev/spring-integration-zmq

Comment: Thanks; I was not aware of that project; we should reach out to the author to see if (s)he wants to contribute it to the extensions repo.

Comment: I am just really need to stay listening a TCP port and have another one for sending messages thought TCP. Is it possible to have this kind of adapters in Spring integration? Maybe I am mixing both technologies because I do not have to manage ZeroMQ server, just rely my messages.

Comment: You might be able to just use the simple [TCP support]http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html().